# Sencha Touch 2.1 calling another view based on MVC

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Using ST 2.1 and MVC I am trying to call another view. Shouldn't I have a view and a controller for each panel? If needed of course. I think a static about page will not need a controller.

So my layout would be.

```
app
 controller
   Main.js
   Contact.js
 view
   Main.js
   Contact.js
   About.js
resources
 css
 images
app.js
index.html
```

Here is my overall project structure.

My app.js calls Main.js. This is my main view and controller. My Main view extends Container. On the Main view I have created a titlebar with left and right buttons and a title. Then I created a panel that holds my main buttons. Then I created a toolbar at the bottom that just has an image.

I want my Main container to change the panel in the middle but keep the top and bottom bars. Each of my views is a panel with various things on them. I can get the overall screen to change but it takes my titlebar and toolbar with it.

I hope this is enough info. Thanks, Donnie

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: My main view has a titlebar, panel, and toolbar. I need the panel to change but keep the titlebar and toolbar in place. All the examples I have found have either not worked or been incomplete or used a navigation bar to navigate. I need to call all my other views from a main screen view with the buttons on the main panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change just the panel you have to put that panel as item into parent panel. When you want to change this panel with other panel or anything else just get reference of parent panel and remove existing content before adding new panel.

```
var p = Ext.getCmp("myPanel");
var pp = Ext.getCmp("parentPanel");
var newPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel', {html : "some content"});
pp.remove(p, true);
pp.add(newPanel);
```

PS - I haven't tested this code, its just guideline.